# jquery drag and drop in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, double-click, onmouseup

I have implemented drag and drop with

```
<div class=\"customNote\" id=\"customNote\" draggable=\"true\" ondragstart=\"moveNote($(this));\" ondblclick=\"showNoteText($(this));\" title=\"Öffne Notitz\"></div>
```

and in function moveNote:

```
$('.document').bind("mouseup.note",function(event) {
//do something
$('.document').unbind("mouseup.note");
}
```

This works find in chrome and firefox, but IE doesn't throw the mouseup event. Instead it is waiting for another mousedown.

It works for IE when I use onmousedown and bind to mousemove. But then I cannot use my ondblclick anymore. I tried to find the number of clicks with setTimeout but it only respond to the first click.

ondragstart and bind to dragstop does not work. It's never dropping then (also not in chrome and firefox).

I also tried "a href=#" instead if the "div", but it didn't help.

Do you have any ideas how to solve that? 
Either onmouseup and a solution that he still recognizes doubleclick 
or dragstop/mouseup with ondragstart.

Answer (score 0):

Folgende Lösung hat funktioniert statt ondragstart und dragend

```
$('.customNote').draggable( {
                    cursor: 'move',
                    helper: 'original',
                    containment: '.document',
                    stop: handleDragStop,
                    revert: 'false'
                  } );

function handleDragStop( event, ui ) {
//do something
}
```